# Trying to convert a SP2010 document version to a PDF generates SPException: List does not exist

Tags: custom-actions, workflow-activity, version-history, word-automation

I am trying to modify an existing SP2010 custom workflow action that converts an existing document to PDF using Word Automation. There is a new requirement to only convert the last published version of a document to PDF. I have been able to iterate through the file versions and find the last published version without too much trouble, but the problem is that when I pass the _vti_history version of the URL to the Word Automation ConversionJob.AddFile() method it generates a "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: List does not exist" error.

The latest version url is "http://myvm/Draft Documents/Test test test.docx"

The latest published version url is "http://myvm/_vti_history/2048/Draft Documents/Test test test.docx"

I am able to enter the URL for the latest published version in the browser and it opens the correct version of the document just fine.

Seeing the AddFile() method is not overloaded and only accepts (string inputURL, string outputUrl), does anyone wnow how I can get a previous version converted to PDF without having to write to a temporary file?

Comment: Have u taken a look with reflector at the code inside AddFile? Probably it will look for a SPList based on the url. Since your published version url is no valid Library it wil throw a valid exception. Have you tried using a library for your temporary file (the version you want to convert?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was hoping to avoid the temporary file solution but it was the only one I could think of. I hadn't thought of using reflector so I'll check it out.

Comment: I think it is rather weird btw, exporting old versions to pdf. Maybe a functionally rework might make it even easier. I have no idea about what you are trying to do but that's just a feeling i have. Can you maybe work around this using the Binary File Data? And don't use the Word Automation Service to convert ? Since this will only work using the latest version and only if your file is in a SPDocumentLibrary

Comment: This is coming from inside AddFile method using reflector: http://pastie.org/4701804 So it queries sharepoint.

Comment: Thanks Frederik for following up on this. I can see from the code segment you posted the problem would be that it is trying to get the inputFile.ParentFolder.ParentListId which it probably can't determine from the starting point of http://myvm/_vti_history/2048/Draft Documents/Test test test.docx.

Comment: FYI, the reason for doing this is that the conversion to PDF is the last step in an approval workflow. As the workflow generates an approval task that can take some time to approve it is possible for the document to be edited further in the mean time. The other option would be to cancel the workflow on document change but in this case it is considered a bit harsh. I think the requirement is valid. I think it is a shame that the Word Automation can't handle it.

Comment: A workaround could be to create a kind of "collection" library to collect all the documents which need to be converted. Coz you basicly want a "snapshot" for when the approval is started. Users will constantly continue to work on the document, so u might need to take a copy and store it in the temp library...